# How do I enforce e.g. a numeric constraint using DataAnnotations?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

I'm trying to utilize model state to validate requests to my WebAPI, but I'm having some trouble with how to control the error messages for some properties. For example, given the following model

```
public class Stuff {

    [Range(0, Double.PositiveInfinity)]
    public double? SomeProp { get; set; }

}
```

(and some infrastructure defined at the bottom of the post) a request with a payload such as `{ someProp: "1.2" }` will model bind correctly - and negative or missing values will give errors - but if I enter something that isn't a valid number (e.g. `{ someProp: "hello" }`) the model state has an error such as

> Error converting value "hello" to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Double]'. Path 'someStuff', line 1, position 41.

(I guess the position is in the JSON object, here cut from a larger request, so don't mind the exact numbers...). For another property, which isn't nullable but instead has a `[Required]` attribute, the error message about a missing required property is included in the model state dict **in addition to** the above message.

I do understand why `"hello"` cannot be bound to a `double?` (or `double`), but regardless of constraints I set in attributes, it seems that the value has to be model bound before they are even checked, and if model binding fails I both get that not-so-friendly message above, as well as all other errors that apply when the value is unset. The only constraint I've been able to apply *before* attempting to bind the value is a Regex, but if that fails I get a similarly user-unfriendly message like

> The field SomeProp must match the regular expression '<my regex>'.

Is there a way to work around this, so that I can give the user a better error message when entering something non-numeric into a textbox that should specify a numeric value?

#### Footnotes: my validation infrastructure

```
[HttpPost]
[Validate]
public IHttpActionResult Validate(Stuff stuff) {
    return Ok();
}
```

where the `Validate` attribute is defined like this:

```
public class ValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
                .CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I struggled with same concept a while back.  Here's what I found and it's super easy.  MVC calls validation routines prior to controller's action method call.  This is why ModelState.IsValid works.  But there's a catch to this, there are two levels of validation 1) The dataannotations level and 2) The implementation of IValidatableObject in the ViewModel or Model. You can turn off the model annotations and implement IValidatableObject in your model to give you 100% control in validation.  It has only 1 method, which you can use Yeild Return ValidationResults.  All properties are there.

Comment: @user1522548: Thanks for the tip about `IValidatableObject`, but in this case it doesn't help me. It seems that the validation happens too late in the request life cycle to be able to tackle the kind of problems I described (namely incorrectly formatted input that can't be model bound in the first place).

Comment: Ok that means only one thing, you must validate at the client, because data-annotations appear to be failing you.  When you say it's too late that tells me the Ajax validation work within MVC is tripping things up.

Comment: @user1522548: I'm not doing *anything* with MVC here - this is in WebAPI. What I'm trying to accomplish is to implement client-side validation through XHR, to avoid having multiple rulesets, so I really want to avoid having extra validation on the client.

Comment: Ok got it.  Take a look at this solution to similar issue.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874026/is-it-possible-to-toggle-validation-data-annotations-on-off-in-mvc-3